# SQL Server - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE collections 
(
    id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts 
(
    id INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    image_URL VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    collection_id INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(collection_id) REFERENCES collections(id)
);

INSERT INTO collections (name) 
VALUES ('Travel'), ('Nature'), ('Great Outdoors');

INSERT INTO posts (title, image_url, author_id, collection_id) 
VALUES ('White Mountains', 'cloudinary.com/snp/balhwpq.jpg', 3, NULL), 
       ('My new car!', 'cloudinary.com/snp/qpcnalpw.jpg', 1, NULL), 
       ('Great weekend for camping', 'cloudinary.com/snp/nmclapa.png', 5, 3), 
       ('Train Ride to France', 'cloudinary.com/snp/rjaptpalw.jpg', 4, 1), 
       ('Small Town in Italy', 'cloudinary.com/snp/aqypqoua.jpg', 4, 1), 
       ('Nice Day At The Air Show', 'cloudinary.com/snp/aswpqlsaq.jpg', 7, NULL), 
       ('Barcelona Beach', 'cloudinary.com/snp/quapwnla.jpg', 9, NULL), 
       ('Gorgeous City of Prague', 'cloudinary.com/snp/anvmapw.png', 3, NULL),
       ('Nothing like fresh Seafood!', 'cloudinary.com/snp/uqnqhapla.jpg', 8, 4), 
       ('Bought a new Swiss army knife', 'cloudinary.com/snp/qanvpauaq.jpg', 6, NULL), 
       ('Delicious meal in Boston', 'cloudinary.com/snp/malvpqlsa.jpg', 10, NULL),
       ('Swimming at Ursa Beach', 'cloudinary.com/snp/poqlanoqlav.jpg', 12, NULL), 
       ('Chilly day in Norway', 'cloudinary.com/snp/vqwlnqposp.jpg', 11, NULL), 
       ('Hiking through beautiful Vermont!', 'cloudinary.com/snp/qpoplnalqi.jpg', 5, 3);
```

Every time I try executing this, it completes the table creation and the first two insert statements and then I get an error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

I believe the problem is that in the posts table Insert statement I'm setting some of the `collection_id` values to NULL which is causing the error. I never said that this column couldn't be NULL, so what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is likely that you are inserting a line where a FK is necessary. if no record can be found in the FK's source table you are getting the above error. Please try to narrow down your problem before posting the full SQL code here.

Comment: I did narrow it down friend, I said above that it gives me the error when I set the 'collection_id' field of the 'posts' table to NULL (3rd insert statement). That's why i'm confused, I never said that field couldn't be NULL so why would that be a problem.

Comment: You could narrow it down further by 1. Excluding the DDL for the tables that aren't part of the problem, 2. Finding out which _actual_ inserted value is the issue. I just ran some of your script and the values clause with a NULL value did not cause an error. So.... again narrow it down.

Comment: In fact there is no suprise here. You are inserting value "4" in your insert script but there is no "4" entry in `collections`

Comment: Okay, I narrowed it down much more. Also, I believe the "4" you were referring to was from a different insert statement, one that doesn't reference 'collections'.

Comment: The forth value for the posts insert (NULL) is definitely what's causing the error for me. I've tried without NULL values and I don't get the error.

Comment: Nope - inserting a null value **will not** generate the foreign key error. Your script is incomplete - which is not helpful. The problem is that you insert 3 rows into Collections - which will generate the values of 1, 2, and 3 as id of those rows. Your script attempts to insert a row into posts with collection_id = 4 - which does not exist and you get the error. And it would help everyone understand your script if you did not cram that giant last insert statement into one line.

Comment: And just to note - you attempt to insert multiple rows with collection_id = null. A basic debugging skill is "divide and conquer". Simply break that single last insert statement into multiple insert statements - one statement per inserted row. That will tell you which rows are generate errors.

Comment: And last comment - this row is the problem -> ('Nothing like fresh Seafood!', 'cloudinary.com/snp/uqnqhapla.jpg', 8, 4),

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I guess I must have missed that. I'm fairly new to SQL so thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have to point at that _every_ one of your comment reponses was incorrect. This is a great site to solve problems but you need to take note of what is being written.

Comment: cannot insert null in foreign key column

Comment: Is that a statement? You certainly can insert NULL into a foreign key column (in the child table). You should try it.